# Get the proxy authentication once we click on a specific page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, page-layout, ajax, json

SharePoint 2013 request: we need to display the proxy authentication window once we click on a specific page link "/index.aspx" .... it can be done using JavaScript ???

Comment: Please open your question a bit more, I'm having hard time figuring out what you mean by "proxy authentication window".

Comment: When i open the SharePoint site from google chrome is requesting to add the my authentication but once it come to IE the site don't ask me for authentication, i need that each time i open the site will ask me for the user & password of my windows authentication  sorry i meant my windows authentication

Answer (score 0):

You don't get authentication prompt on IE because IE is automatically signing you in to SharePoint using the credentials you've used when logging into Windows.

Internet Explorer can be configured to prompt for credentials when connecting to servers requiring authentication. For example, IE can prompt you for a user name and password when you connect to servers in Trusted sites that require authentication, as opposed to using the credentials you are logged on with.

To configure IE to prompt for credentials for Trusted sites:

1. Open Internet Explorer.
2. From the Tools menu, click Internet Options.
3. Select the Security tab.
4. Click the Trusted sites Web content zone.
5. Click the Custom level button.
6. From the list of settings, scroll to the end and select the button beside
7. Prompt for user name and password.
8. Click OK.
9. Click OK to close the Internet Options window.

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabhkv/archive/2009/06/16/configure-ie-to-prompt-for-credentials-for-trusted-sites-windows-fanatics.aspx)

Comment: Yes thanks for the above information but if I need to do it as a script to popup the windows authentication on the load of a specific page since I cannot go on each user and configure the IE for him on my company since the IT guys have his own security policy

Comment: Not possible with JavaScript or other easy server side trick, sorry. You either need to use some other browser than IE, extend SharePoint web application and use FBA, or ask IT to centrally push the above modification to IEs.